# Type name is not allowed

Tags: c++

Hice la sobrecarga del operador `[]` usando un template, pero al tratar de usarlo me marca el error `type name is not allowed`. Tengo una clase `Variables` así:

```cpp
class Variables {
private:
    map<string, Token> variables;
    map<string, Funcion> funciones;
public:
    void agregar(string nombre, Token token) { variables[nombre] = token; }

    template <class T>
    T& operator [](const string nombre) { 
        if(variables.find(nombre) != variables.end()) return variables[nombre]; 
        return funciones[nombre];
    }
}
```

Por si quieren la clase Token es algo así:

```cpp
class Token {
private:
    string valor;
public:
    Token();
    Token(string valor_): valor(valor_) {}
    string getValor(){ return valor; }
};
```

Al momento de obtener el valor mediante la notación de corchetes, el editor me marca error

```cpp
Token token;
Variables vars;
vars.agregar("holas", Token("holas"));

token = vars<Token>["holas"]; //aqui me marca el error
```

Comment: Ahora me marca el error `name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`

Comment: jaja, ahora el error es `a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function`

Comment: Te falta pasar un parámetro a la función `agregar`

Comment: @Mateo perdón, se me olvidó. Ya edité la pregunta

Comment: @Trauma se me olvidó decir que `Funcion` hereda de `Token`

Comment: @Trauma perdón, error mío, esta usando corchetes en vez de paréntesis >_< Ahora ya me anda perfecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador de indizado (`operator []`) no puede usarse con lista de argumentos de plantilla:

```
token = vars<Token>["holas"];
//          ~~~~~~~ <--- Error
```

Así que debes quitarlo, pero entonces surge otro error:

```
// Error, no se puede deducir el argumento plantilla 'T'
token = vars["holas"];
```

Así que debes invocar el operador de indizado en formato función:

```
Token token = vars.operator[]<Token>("holas");
```

Pero entonces el error es otro:

```
template <class T>
T& operator [](const string nombre) { 
    if(variables.find(nombre) != variables.end()) return variables[nombre]; 
    // Error, el retorno es 'Token' pero devuelves 'Funcion'
    return funciones[nombre];
}
```

Así que debes cambiar la instrucción `return`:

```
template <class T>
T& operator [](const string nombre) { 
    if(variables.find(nombre) != variables.end()) return variables[nombre]; 
    // Error, el retorno es 'Token' pero devuelves 'Funcion'
    return variables[nombre];
}
```